# How to set focus on updated row after updating row in DataGridView?

Tags: vb.net

How to set focus on updated row after updating row in DataGridView?

i want to set focus on updated row after updating the rows and then display the datagrridview

DataGridView.CurrentCell = DataGridView.Rows(RowIndex)...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use

```
    'update en refresh your datagrid like so.
    myDataGrid.Update()
    myDataGrid.Refresh()

    'fill in the correct rowindex and column index and this will select/focus the 
    'correct row.
    myDataGrid.Select(rowIndex, ColumnIndex)
```